# Create a dynamic custom sort VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am sure there is a post covering this and I am just not finding it, so apologies for any repost.

I have a range of data on one sheet. I have a dynamic list of the order I need the data to be sorted by in a custom sort on another sheet. I am trying to figure out how to create a custom sort list in based on the data in sheet two to sort the data from Sheet one by. The closest I was able to come up with is defining the 28 sorts and assigning them to variables. However the list never actually sorts

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array(FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5, _
    FC6, FC7, FC8, FC9, FC10, FC11, FC12, FC13, FC14, FC15, FC16, FC17 _
    , FC18, FC19, FC20, FC21, FC22, FC23, FC24, FC25, FC26, FC27, FC28)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "F2:F300000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "FC1 , FC2,FC3,FC4,FC5,Fc6,FC7,FC8,FC9,FC10,FC11,FC12,FC13,FC14,FC15,FC16,FC17,FC18,FC19,FC20,FC21,FC22,FC23,FC24,FC25,FC26,FC27,FC28" _
    , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:V300000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

In my debugging attempts I suspect my issue stems from the line:

```
CustomOrder:= _
    "FC1 , FC2,FC3,FC4,FC5,Fc6,FC7,FC8,FC9,FC10,FC11,FC12,FC13,FC14,FC15,FC16,FC17,FC18,FC19,FC20,FC21,FC22,FC23,FC24,FC25,FC26,FC27,FC28" _
```

The Array recognizes each variable as it's value. However the custom order does not. I am assuming, because it is in quotes and is looking at it like a string.

Comment: You actually have 30 declared variables named `FCxx`? In any case, Excel knows nothing about the VBA runtime context / your variables; `F18` is only meaningful in VBA, depending on the scope of the variables' declarations.

Comment: There are 1-28, That would be 28 variables.

The line that I highlighted in my post the FCxx do not read as variables when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these 28 variables hold your custom sort order, what you want is to make a string out of the *values* held by these identifiers.

> ```
> CustomOrder:= _
>     "FC1 , FC2,FC3,FC4,FC5,Fc6,FC7,FC8,FC9,FC10,FC11,FC12,FC13,FC14,FC15,FC16,FC17,FC18,FC19,FC20,FC21,FC22,FC23,FC24,FC25,FC26,FC27,FC28"
> ```

That's making a string out of the identifiers themselves - IOW your intuition is correct.

So instead of re-listing the 28 variables into a string literal, use the part of [HackSlash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161406/1188513) that sets the `CustomOrder` index:

```
CustomOrder:=Application.CustomListCount
```

That should work as long as the last added custom list is the custom list you just defined and added.

So:

```
Application.AddCustomList _
    ListArray:=Array(FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5, FC6, FC7, _
                     FC8, FC9, FC10, FC11, FC12, FC13, FC14, _
                     FC15, FC16, FC17, FC18, FC19, FC20, FC21, _
                     FC22, FC23, FC24, FC25, FC26, FC27, FC28)

Dim pickList As Worksheet
Set pickList = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List")

pickList.Sort.SortFields.Clear
pickList.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=pickList.Range("F2:F300000"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:=Application.CustomListCount, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With pickList.Sort
    .SetRange pickList.Range("A1:V300000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

That said, having 28 variables with essentially the same name plus a numeric suffix, is a *code smell* begging for a *data structure*: instead of 28 variables, you should have *one* variable containing a single-dimensional array with 28 slots.

```
Dim fcValues(1 To 28)
fcValues(1) = "the value you gave to FC1"
fcValues(2) = "the value you gave to FC2"
'...
fcValues(28) = "the value you gave to FC28"
```

If the variables' values came from a worksheet, then its even easier (assuming a single-column `sourceRange`):

```
Dim fcValues As Variant
fcValues = Application.Transpose(sourceRange.Value)
```

Such an array could be passed as-is to the `ListArray` argument of `AddCustomList`:

```
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=fcValues
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 28 variables that you want to name 1 to 28 you should make an array. Then you can just pass that to the ListArray parameter.

Now, we can address the fact that CustomOrder is a variant that can accept a string or an integer. Nobody seems to know why because the M$ documentation is lacking on this property. From what I can tell the code below will work because we've added a new customlist and then we select the last one by citing the number of total lists as the CustomOrder.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CustomSort()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim FC(1 to 28) As String

    PopulateFCValues() ' This is an imaginary sub that populates the FC Array

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=FC

    Dim sortNum As Long
    sortNum = Application.CustomListCount

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F300000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=sortNum, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pick List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:V300000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the custom list use "FCxx" string literals (or range addresses), rather than the variables OP means to use (which we don't know where they come from nor what they contain)?

Comment: I didn't consider that those could be variables. If they are, they should be an array. `Dim FC(27) as String` Then it could be passed directly to ListArray... That would replace kayRange my example.

Comment: That's quite literally what I did - replacing `keyRange` in your example. If you edit your answer to work with an array of variables I'll delete mine - yours was first, and is entirely correct save the part where OP clarifies (albeit in the comments section) that they're using 28 variables. Mine is just a rip-off with cosmetic tweaks =)